# asset / advantage

Tags: grammar

Can I use the word asset in this context:

My experience in this area is an asset with my job tasks.

I don't know if i should use it, and the with seems awkward, but I couldn't find any example for what I'm trying to say.

Would advantage be better suited? If so, should I use it with "with"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

We generally say that something is an "asset *to*" something else, not "with." I would also be more specific that the benefactor is probably not the tasks themselves, but their performance or completion:

**My experience in this area is an asset to the performance of my tasks.**

Comment: I don't think we do say that. I would say "this is an asset in this job".

Comment: @DJClayworth I'd probably say that as well, more importantly, whether I used _in_, _to_ or any other preposition, I would just say "job" not "job tasks"